# Почему не работает request

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Код:

```py
def page(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello!")
```

Программа выводит:

> "request" is not accessedPylance

Comment: Это предупреждение. Что у вас есть параметр метода, который в нём не используется. Зачем он тогда в сигнатуре метода, если он не нужен?

Comment: @CrazyElf затем что Django требует

Comment: Все что выдает pylance - это предупреждения, а не ошибки. Как-то на них реагировать или игнорировать - это на усмотрение программиста. Если у вас что-то действительно не работает (как указано в заголовке), опишите что конкретно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Это **не** ошибка. Это предупреждение о том, что у вас есть `request`, который нигде не используется внутри функции. `Pylance` предупреждает, что есть аргумент, который не влияет на ответ функции. Программа, не смотря на это, всё равно будет работать. Так работает `Django`.